# How can I add a Java system property during JUnit Test Execution

Tags: gradle, junit

I need to define a system property for my JUnit tests.  I've tried various steps to pass the name/value pair into gradle. (I've tried Milestone-3 and 4).
None of these approaches worked:

- defining a systemProp.foo=bar in the gradle.properties file
- passing -Dfoo=bar at the command line
- passing -PsystemProp.foo=bar on the command line

I don't see the additional properties from "gradle properties" though I'm not sure I should.  But more importantly, I dumped the System.properties in a static initializer and the property is not there.  I need to pass System properties to the running tests to tell them what environment (local, Jenkins, etc) they are running in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question.  Just stumbled upon the solution [here](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1185):

test {
systemProperties = System.properties
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer!   Was being hit by this strange behavior as well.   Seems like that should be the default IMO, not something we all need to add....

Comment: Finally, I found this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can also define individual properties like this:

```
test {
  systemProperty "file", "test.story"
}
```

(From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855839/3195526))

Answer (score 0):

with android, you can use

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    ...
    // Encapsulates options for local unit tests.
    unitTests {
      // By default, local unit tests throw an exception any time the code you are testing tries to access
      // Android platform APIs (unless you mock Android dependencies yourself or with a testing
      // framework like Mockito). However, you can enable the following property so that the test
      // returns either null or zero when accessing platform APIs, rather than throwing an exception.
      returnDefaultValues true

      // Encapsulates options for controlling how Gradle executes local unit tests. For a list
      // of all the options you can specify, read Gradle's reference documentation.
      all {
        // Sets JVM argument(s) for the test JVM(s).
        jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'

        // You can also check the task name to apply options to only the tests you specify.
        if (it.name == 'testDebugUnitTest') {
          systemProperty 'debug', 'true'
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```