# Using command line arguments or system properties from a Parameterized Junit test?

Tags: groovy, junit, junit4, gradle

I use this method to setup my parameterized data:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getStories() {
        Collection<Object[]> allStories = new ArrayList<Object[]>()
        new File(SPEC_DIRECTORY).eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
            if (file.getName().endsWith('.story')) {
                Object[] args = [file.getName(), file]
                allStories << args
            }
        }
        return allStories
    }
```

I invoke the main test with gradle via `gradle test`, but I do not seem to be able to see system properties.

If I use the invocation `gradle -Dfile=test.story`, then `System.getProperty('file')` is undefined. How can I pass arguments to this parameterized data builder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a Java system property during JUnit Test Execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878243/how-can-i-add-a-java-system-property-during-junit-test-execution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle runs all tests in a separate JVM. You have to configure the `test` task:

```
test {
    systemProperty "file", "test.story"
}
```

For more information, see the [Gradle DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html).

Comment: This no longer seems to work in milestone 9. Has this changed?

Comment: I don't think anything has changed here. Are you absolutely sure that the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. Eh.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - The above doesn't seem to work for me, I'm using juint 4.12, I use this in my gradle.build file - 
test {
    systemProperty "Browser", "Chrome"
}
And I try to access the system property in a junit test by System.getProperty("Browser"). But I always get the value as null. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of any beginners out there(like myself) who stumble upon this question; I'd like to explicitly mention that the systemProperty in gradle test task simply passes on system properties to the test jvm. So if you simply use

```
test{
systemProperty 'Chrome', 'Browser' }
```

You won't be able to access the property in your junit tests via ' System.getProperty("Browser") ' . Instead it needs to be coupled with the command gradle test -DBrowser=Chrome

The above case is merely an illustration and it would probably make sense to use -

```
test{
    systemProperty 'Chrome', System.getProperty('Browser') }
```

along with

```
gradle test -DBrowser=Chrome
```